What does AZ^4 = -3 (mod p) mean in the context of elliptic curve cryptography?
In the documentation of TeraFire® cryptocore, the following statement is given (page 14):

For For elliptic curves of the form y² = x³ + Ax + B, if there exists a solution to AZ^4 = -3 (mod p), then [...].

I am not sure what the rhs of the equation means: "-3 (mod p)". Is it the remainder of the division of -3 with p? In that case, for all values of p that are larger then 3 the result is just -3, which doesn't really make sense... There's probably something that I am overlooking?

$-3 = p -3 \bmod p$ so it is a short writing.

@kelaka,
Thanks for the reply.
So you have to replace the rhs by p - 3 mod p? That makes little sense still... Remainder of 3 divided by p for any p larger than 3 is equal to 3... So basically, it is just p - 3 then?
So, Z^4 = (p - 3)/A?

Most of the part of your comment makes no sense to me. Yes  $Z^4 = (p-3)A^{-1} \bmod p$. $/A$ is represents the inverse of $A$ in $\bmod p$. Make sure that you read at least a basic algebra book since you are dealing with curves

Actually, as electronics engineer, I studied (linear) algebra extensively and I also now what a modulo division is but since I am new to cryptography, I am not familiar with standard notations in cryptography and it is rather difficult to find some explanation that is understandable for somebody new to the field...
I found somewhere that what is meant with a = b (mod c) is equal to the statement: a and b have the same remainder when they are divided by c., so they are called "congruent". Not sure how that works when b is negative, though.. I guess to check that a - b (=a+3) is divisible by p?

This is really a question about how things in modular arithmetic are written out by convention.
When we write the values $a$ and $b$ modulo $c$, we consider $a$ and $b$ to be the same they differ by an integer multiple of $c$.  For example, if we say $3 = 15 \pmod{12}$, we're saying that $3$ and $15$ are the same (modulo $12$) because they differ by a multiple of $12$.  In this case, the $\pmod{12}$ is not an operation on $15$, but really is saying "we're looking not at the integer values, but instead the modulo $12$ values"
That is, in modulo $12$, we consider $3$ and $15$ to be different ways of writing the same value.  This value is canonically called $3$, however $15$ is just as good of a way to write this, as is $-9$ and $75$.
So, going to your question, if we say:
$$AZ^4 = -3 \pmod p$$
We're saying that $AZ^4$ and $-3$ are the 'same value' modulo $p$; their integer values are different by some multiple of $p$.
Now, one canonical way of writing $-3$ is $p-3$, however writing $p-3$ can be seen as injecting a $p$ that doesn't need to be there, hence we generally write that value as the shorter $-3$.
And, this condition can be tested by checking if $AZ^4 \bmod p$ is $p-3$.

thanks for the reply!
So to find the "twist factor", Z, based on A and p, you would calculate p - 3 and multiply this with the inverse of A (mod p)? Then the 4th root of that number? Is there any special way of calculating the 4th root, considering the modular nature of this equation?

@Botteries: well, the most straightforward way to compute 4th roots is to take two consecutive square roots.  To compute a modular squareroot, it is easiest if $p=3 \pmod 4$ (which is usually true for elliptic curve modulii); in that case, the squareroots of $x$ (if they exist) are $y = x^{(p+1)/4}$ and $-y$.  Note: not all values have squareroots, and so you'd need to double check whether $y^2 = x$.

What would be the best practical way to find/calculate the twist factor if p and a are very large integers?

@Botteries: pretty much as you outlined: compute $x = -3A^{-1}$, and then $y = x^{(p-1)/4}$ and then $z = y^{(p-1)/4}$ (checking if $y^2 = x$ (if that's true, then $z^2 = y$ will be true as well, if that's not true, then there's no fourth-root)

Unfortunately, our p is a 256 bit number, so calculating the (p-1)/4 power by multiplying that many times would take forever. I found this, maybe that is more efficient? I'll try it.
https://gist.github.com/nakov/60d62bdf4067ea72b7832ce9f71ae079

@Botteries It uses pow; generally, the power is executed with (modular) repeated squaring algorithm and variants. They are quite fast.
